# Volume inside another volume use www-data instead of root

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm using the following Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml.

I'm including the volume "vendor" inside the "/var/www" volume. The "vendor" folder is being created automatically when running the docker-compose file. But it gets created with chown "root:root", while all other folders inside "/var/www" chowned to "www-data:www-data".

Any idea how I can fix it so that the "vendor" volume is also chowned by www-data by default?

**Dockerfile**

```
...
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data
...
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    - vendor:/var/www/vendor

volumes:
  vendor:
```

**"ls -la" on the "/var/www" shows the following:**

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data    0 Mar 15 20:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 15 20:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data    0 Mar 15 20:42 test
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Mar 15 20:38 vendor
```

Comment: can you share your complete Dockerfile please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use workaround, just create folder in Dockerfile, permission will be saved, as an example:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM caa06d9c/support

RUN mkdir /var/www/ && chown 1000:1000 /var/www

CMD [ "sleep", "9999" ]
```

**Docker Compose**
    version: "3.2"

```
services:
    srv:
        image:  temp
        volumes:
            - vendor:/var/www/

volumes:
    vendor:
```

**Output**

```
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Jul  5  2018 spool
drwxrwxrwt    2 root     root          4096 Jul  5  2018 tmp
drwxr-xr-x    2 1000     1000          4096 Mar 15 21:06 www
```

Comment: Thanks, although it's a workaround. This seems to be the solution I was looking for!